# [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "Error: {"clientConfig":{},"port":443,"servicePath":"vision.googleapis.com","scopes":

Tags: node.js, vue.js, google-vision

I try to implement **google vision api** in **Vuejs** but I getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "Error: {"clientConfig":{},"port":443,"servicePath":"vision.googleapis.com","scopes":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision"]}You need to pass auth instance to use gRPC-fallback client in browser. Use OAuth2Client from google-auth-library."
```

**My code for read text from image:**

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

// Performs label detection on the image file
client
.textDetection('./myimage.png')
.then(result => {
 const texts = result[0].textAnnotations;
 console.log('Text:');
 texts.forEach(text => console.log(text.description));
 })
.catch(err => {
 console.error('ERROR:', err);
 });
```

Any idea how to solve?

Comment: How are you authenticating? Note this part of the error message: "You need to pass auth instance to use gRPC-fallback client in browser. Use OAuth2Client from google-auth-library."

Comment: @Brendan I use `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=api.json` to do it
Ps: my credential file name is api.json

Comment: Where do you set it? Does it have the right path to the json file?

Comment: @Brendan I put the json file into Vue project that I created, thats where I set it